# Get values from a histogram without using plt

Tags: python, histogram

Is there any way to get the values in "x" and "y" of a histogram without graphing** it? I use the function below many times (in each loop) in my code, and I noticed that my code gets slower and slower in each loop.

** I am not sure if what it does internally is to graph but I know that the slowness in my code is related to the function "plt.hist" despite using plt.close(). Thank you.

```
# a is a list
def function_hist(a, ini, final):

    # 12 bins
    bins = np.linspace(ini, final, 13)
    weightsa = np.ones_like(a)/float(len(a))
    y, x, _ = plt.hist(a, bins, weights = weightsa)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348548/any-way-to-create-histogram-with-matplotlib-pyplot-without-plotting-the-histogra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to create histogram with matplotlib.pyplot without plotting the histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348548/any-way-to-create-histogram-with-matplotlib-pyplot-without-plotting-the-histogra)

Answer (score 10):

Use [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

You can modify your function as below

```
# a is a list
def function_hist(a, ini, final):

    # 12 bins
    bins = np.linspace(ini, final, 13)
    weightsa = np.ones_like(a)/float(len(a))
    hist = np.histogram(np.array(a), bins, weights = weightsa)
```